# How to use generic.ListView without Python interpreting ".L" as a separate syntax?

Tags: python, django

I'm defining a generic index view in Django, but when calling "generic.ListView" as a parameter, for some reason Python interprets the ".L" from .ListView as something else, and returns a syntax error.

It works fine with generic.DetailView, and it's only when an L follows a period that it's interpreted differently. I tried Googling what the .L was, if there had been a change to how .ListView is called, etc. to no avail

This is the Index call:

```
def IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'form/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_entries_list'
```

This is the Detail call, which works just fine:

```
def DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Info
    template_name = 'form/detail.html'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "Python interprets the ".L" from .ListView as something else"? Do you get an error? Can you share the error traceback and the code where you get it?

Comment: Both of those are syntax errors - the names of parameters have to be a single identifier.  Maybe you meant `class` instead of `def`?

Comment: def should be `class`

Comment: @ShafikurRahman This was it, thanks!

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use  class instead of def

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/